# Tortoise SVN does not show the folder structure?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I am using Tortoise SVN Client for remotely connect SVN server from centos.
My SVN server installed in Centos 7 and Tortoise SVN Client installed in windows 7.

Created new project in SVN Server with branches, trunk, tags.
It was showing branches, trunk, tags in browser successfully.
But Tortoise SVN Client does not show the branches, trunk, tags. 
How can i solve it.

[image]

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: If you get no errors while connecting, then just stupid question: are you sure that you are looking into the same repo in browser and in TortoiseSVN?

Comment: in that project having three folders inside like branches,tags,trunk but it not showing that for that only i am asking?

Comment: Do you open the same URL on browser and in Tortoise SVN client on the same machine with windows 7?